# Setup Factory 9 - Check File for String

Tags: scripting, setup-factory

Im am 100% new to Lua and need a way to check my `etc/hosts` file for a string. The other posts I found were dealing with searching in strings and and reading files line by line.

Here is some of my script which is a combination of some of the examples I found on here:

```
file = io.open("C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts", "a")
function check(file)
    if file.match(str, "nbs") then
        file:close()
        Screen.Next();
    else            
        file:write("\n", %UserIP%, " nbs document")
        file:close()
        Screen.Next();
        end
end;
```

As you can see Im searching the file `hosts` for the sting `nbs`. If it exists I want to move on. If it does not, I plan to append the file with a new line.
The above seems to do nothing when I enter it into my Lua Shell.

**EDIT 1:** adding full script; this is the full original script + my additions

```
-- These actions are performed when the Next button is clicked.

-- from _SUF70_Global_Functions.lua:
-- is the "Name:" field empty?
if(g_EditFieldIsEmpty(CTRL_EDIT_01)) then

    -- the name field is empty...tell the user that it's a required field
    -- and remain on this screen (don't advance to the next one)

    -- "Invalid Entry"
    local strTitle = SetupData.GetLocalizedString("MSG_INVALID_ENTRY");

    -- get the label for the "Name:" edit field (since it may have been translated)
    local strFieldName = DlgStaticText.GetProperties(CTRL_STATICTEXT_LABEL_01).Text;

    -- strip off the trailing ":" (if present)
    strFieldName = String.TrimRight(strFieldName, ":");

    -- "The <fieldname> field cannot be empty."
    local strPrompt = SetupData.GetLocalizedString("MSG_THE")
                    ..strFieldName
                    ..SetupData.GetLocalizedString("MSG_FIELD_CANNOT_BE_EMPTY");

    Dialog.Message(strTitle, strPrompt, MB_OK, MB_ICONEXCLAMATION, MB_DEFBUTTON1);
else
    --andrew you added the lines below
    file = io.open("C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts", "a")
    function check(file)
        if file.match(str, "test") then
            file:close()
            Screen.Next()
        else            
            file:write("\n", "test")
            file:close()
            Screen.Next();
        end
    end;
    -- the "Name:" field isn't empty...so
    -- advance to the next screen
--  Screen.Next();
end;
```

Comment: I'm sure you can find a better error description than "seems to do nothing". is there no error message?

Comment: @Piglet there is not. Im making sure my test environment is set up correctly.

Comment: is this all your code?

Comment: @Piglet no it is a small addition to an applications (Setup Factory 9) script. I will add the full script.

Comment: You need to use double backslashes in the path (In Lua 5.2+ you'll get an error): `"C:\\Windows\\System32\\drivers\\etc\\hosts"`. Single forward slashes should also work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up being the solution I was looking for:

```
ip = SessionVar.Expand("%UserIP%")
result = TextFile.ReadToString(SessionVar.Expand("%SystemFolder%\\drivers\\etc\\hosts"));
if string.match(result, "nbs") then
    Screen.Next()
else
    file = io.open("C:\\Windows\\System32\\drivers\\etc\\hosts", "a")
    file:write("\n", ip, " nbs document")
    file:close()
    Screen.Next()
end
```

In this case I was using the applications built in functions. These seem to make use of C as well so they would not work in a Lua shell.

Answer (score 0):

Your code creates a file handle and defines a function check().

If it is supposed to do more you have to have to add more content. Like a function call to check.

Once you call check you'll most likely face a script error because you call a function file.match which does not exist in native Lua.

```
file = io.open("C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts", "a")
-- this loop will give you each line of the file as a string and you can use string.match
for line in file:lines() do
  if line:match("nbs") then
    print("I found one!!")
  end
end
```

I'm sure you can take it from here. Please refer to https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.8